# How to set Fortran compiler path in Meson?

Tags: compilation, fortran, meson-build

I know we can use the `FC` flag to set the preferred Fortran Compiler's name. But is there any way I can specify the path to a compiler and Meson will use that particular compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FC` flags accepts the path of compiler as well.